# Win Batch - Append text to TSV file on every line

Tags: batch-file

I have a number of TSV files in a directory, and I would like to append the file name as an extra column on every line.
For Example my data looks like the below.

**BEFORE**

*FileName:*    snapper_User_list.txt

```
Username    group        
user1 admin  
user2 users
```

*FileName:* marlin_User_list.txt

```
Username    group  
root admin  
sql admin
```

My ideal state would to be have one text file that looks like the below.

**AFTER**

*FileName:*    output.txt

```
user1 admin snapper  
user 2 users snapper  
root admin marlin  
sql admin marlin
```

For now I need to complete this in MS Windows.

I have the below script working, although it still displays the full filename in my output.

```
Rem Rename the files by just using the name before the underscore.
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%i in ( 'dir *.txt /b' ) do (
    rename %%i_%%j %%i.txt
    )

Rem Combine the files.
FOR %%I IN (*.txt) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (%%I) DO (
        echo %%a%TAB%%%I>>combined.txt
        )
    )
```

It's pretty ugly code.

Thanks.
(updated - update to my code)

Comment: What underscore? The 1st underscore that appears in the original TSV file, or the 1st underscore in the file name? It would help if you gave a before and after example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you are referring to an underscore that occurs in the file name.

```
@echo off
setlocal

::The following defines a TAB character that is not preserved on StackOverflow
set "TAB=   "

for %%F in (*.txt) do call :processFile "%%F"
exit /b

:processFile
set "name=%~1"
set name=%name:_=&rem %
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (%1) do echo %%a%TAB%%name%>>combined.txt
```

The magic command is `set name=%name:_=&rem %`. It works by injecting a REMark command into the statement. Assume the current name is `part1_part2.txt`. After the search and replace expansion, the full statement becomes `set name=part1&rem part2.txt`

**EDIT - Improved answer**

Looking at your edited question, I realize there is a better way. I should have thought of parsing the name using FOR /F :-)  You were 90% there!

```
@echo off
setlocal

::The following defines a TAB character that is not preserved on StackOverflow
set "TAB=   "

for %%F in (*.txt) do (
  for /f "delims=_" %%I in ("%%F") do (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%F") do echo %%a%TAB%%%I>>combined.txt
  )
)
```